# how to compute the MSE?

Tags: r, function, mse

I have to compute the MSE of the value "Td" without packaging. I used a function but I have always the same MSE (see MSE_mod1) for each row (it shouldn't be the same MSE between lines, right?). Do you know why?

Could you help me? :)

Here is my code:

```
fonction_MSE <- function(tdval, td) {
  
  n<- 8741
  diff<- tdval-td
  MSEmode1<- (1/n)*sum((diff)^2)
  print(round(MSEmode1, digits = 9))    
}

MSE_mod1 <- fonction_MSE(meteo_charleroi[, "Td"], meteo_charleroi[, "Td_mod1"])

MSE_mod2 <- fonction_MSE(meteo_charleroi[, "Td"], meteo_charleroi[, "Td_mod2"])
```

here is the head of my data frame:

[head of data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhjRI.png)

Comment: the head of your data.frame is missing

Comment: Perhaps a better question is: are the results of your models different? Maybe calculate `mod_difference <- meteo_charleroi[, "Td_mod1"] - meteo_charleroi[, "Td_mod2"]` and look `summary(mod_difference)`. Perhaps you have a typo in assigning the model results to the data frame, or something like that.

Comment: sorry, I juste edited now

Answer (score 1):

Why not just using:

```
mean((tdval-td)^2)
```